# Is it possible to add a label on splash screen in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to show a label on splash screen if I am not connected to the internet is it possible to add a label on splash screen in iOS or in some other way I can show the label at the starting of the application.

Comment: The actual splash screen is fixed; whether you use an image or a storyboard scene in ios8+. You can make your first scene identical to your splash scene and add dynamic content there

Answer (score 1):

The `LaunchScreen.storyboard` can only be used to display static elements like `UILabel`s, `UIImage`s, etc. This is well explained in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612217/can-i-animate-an-image-ios8-launchscreen-xib).

I assume from your question that you want to check first if a user has an internet connection before allowing him to continue to the main application. If this is the case, then you can do the following:

- Create an static `LaunchScreen.storyboard` with only static elements (like your application logo)
- Copy the elements in your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and past them in your initial view controller.
- Add a label for informing the user if they are connected to the internet and check for it in your view controller.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS8 and later you can use XIB files and place whatever you want there (labels, images, buttons).
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) you can find the details
It's convenient because you don't have to produce several launch images. Instead you can use single XIB file with autoresized elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change launch screen content dynamically but you can add your custom launch `UIViewController` with a `UILabel` inside it as the first screen of the application. Here, you can check for Network Connection using Apple's Reachability class. connect the `UILabel` to your launch `UIViewController` class and Change the `UILabel` text according to your requirement.

Then present your application root view from this class whenever required.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(openNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

-(void) openNextView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HOME" sender:nil];
}
```